# PhantomJS JavaScript errors from gstatic, but not in browser

Tags: google-maps, capybara, phantomjs

I recently ran our website through our PhantomJS testing suite and ran into JavaScript errors that I can't reproduce in my browser manually. These errors are found in the Google maps api and the text returned by Capybara is as follows:

```
TypeError: Unable to delete property.
TypeError: Unable to delete property.
   at :215
   at https://maps.gstatic.com/maps-api-v3/api/js/19/3/main.js:20 in cf
   at https://maps.gstatic.com/maps-api-v3/api/js/19/3/main.js:20 in cf
   at https://maps.gstatic.com/maps-api-v3/api/js/19/3/main.js:19
   at :214
   at https://maps.gstatic.com/maps-api-v3/api/js/19/3/main.js:20 in cf
   at https://maps.gstatic.com/maps-api-v3/api/js/19/3/main.js:20 in cf
   at https://maps.gstatic.com/maps-api-v3/api/js/19/3/main.js:21
   at :176
   at :31
   at https://maps.gstatic.com/maps-api-v3/api/js/19/3/main.js:26 in Yf
   at :178
```

Is this a known bug with Capybara, PhantomJS, or the Google maps API? Could the problem be caused by the user agent string in PhantomJS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the latest experimental version of Google Maps (v3.19), which includes a workaround, fixed this problem for me: https://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=7475#c20

[Edit] Google Maps v3.19 was [released as the production version on 17 Feb 2015](https://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/wiki/JavascriptMapsAPIv3Changelog). Also, PhantomJS version 2 was released on 23 Jan 2015 incorporating an [updated WebKit module](http://phantomjs.org/releases.html) which doesn't exhibit the `Unable to delete property` problem.

Answer (score 4):

I'm using Cucumber / Poltergeist and I hacked around this in by creating the following extension:

/features/support/env.rb

```rb
Capybara::Poltergeist::Driver.new(app, 
  :extensions => ["features/support/ignore_gmaps_errors.js"]
)
```

/features/support/ignore_gmaps_errors.js

```js
window.onerror = function(message) {
  if (message == 'TypeError: Unable to delete property.') {
    console.log('Ignoring gmaps error');
    return false;
  } else {
    return true;
  }
};
```

Comment: I tried this solution for RSpec and it worked well. Thank you.

Comment: Just a note to say if you have any other `"TypeError: Unable to delete property"` errors, these will be silently ignored, but I wasn't able to make it any more specific to the google maps error and this was the only way I could get it working.

Answer (score 3):

Google maps API experimental version was updated this morning (12/11) causing this breakage. By default when you include:

`<script src="//maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?libraries=places"></script>`

it uses the [latest experimental version](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/basics#Versioning). Locking yourself to the latest release version:

`<script src="//maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3&libraries=places"></script>`

should fix this.

Comment: While this helped temporarily, the update has now (apparently) been pushed to the release version and these changes no longer help.

Comment: Since this no longer works, I am removing the answer. I've filed a bug with the google maps api people and we'll see where that goes.

Comment: No need to remove the answer, but please edit it and add a note on top that it doesn't work anymore. It's too easy to miss the comments.

Comment: Can you share the bug report URL to track this?

Comment: I'm running into the same issue. I've tested it with `<script src="//maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js"></script>` and `<script src="//maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.18"></script>` (according to https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/basics#Versioning). Any news on this?

Comment: You can track the issue here: https://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=7475

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the user agent to

> Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.0) AppleWebKit/535.1 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/13.0.782.41 Safari/535.1

Google delivers JavaScript that is not entirely runnable with its default user agent. PhantomJS 1.x is based on a really old fork of QtWebKit which is comparable to Chrome 13 (the reason for that user agent string).

It [looks like](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15733827/capybara-poltergeist-and-phantomjs-and-giving-an-empty-response-in-body) you can do this this way:

```
@session = Capybara::Session.new(:poltergeist)
@session.driver.headers = { 'User-Agent' => 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.0) AppleWebKit/535.1 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/13.0.782.41 Safari/535.1' }
```

Comment: I am getting the same error as the OP using capybara-webkit. I set the user agent to the suggested and am still getting the `TypeError: Unable to delete property` error. The error only happens for me when I attempt to use the geocoder module. This error started suddenly this morning.

Comment: Ok, this suggests that the problem is not in PhantomJS or capybara-webkit, but capybara itself. Is there the same problem with some different driver? I just tried it again with plain PhantomJS and there are no errors with or without the above user agent string.

Comment: what did you try precisely? My code is: https://gist.github.com/sgringwe/f7d9859417d8638abf25

Comment: I did [this](https://gist.github.com/artjomb/82bce4ba312f63abb72a), but when I first wrote the script, GM actually used the maps API, now it doesn't anymore. At least not the public one.