# TypeError: Unable to delete property

Tags: google-maps-api-3

Even when the most basic map loads the following error is shown:

**TypeError: Unable to delete property.**

This has to do with the zoom, as with any zooming, the error is shown again.

I have tried to reset the map to v 3.5
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3

and it worked for a few days, then the same error happened again.

Going back even further to v3 would not help anymore. What happened and how could this be fixed?

BTW: the problem does NOT occur with CHROME/FIREFOX BUT with SAFARI (5.1.1)

Comment: possibly related issues in the issue tracker: [Issue 7475](https://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=7475),  [Issue 7480](https://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=7480).  The lowest numbered version currently available is 3.17 (see [Versioning](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/basics?csw=1#Versioning) in the documentation)

Comment: I added comments to Issue 7475 mentioned as we are experiencing the same issues when printing with PhantomJS.

Comment: PhantomJS problems should be fixed as of gmaps 3.19 released on 17 Feb 2015 - see also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27429129/phantomjs-javascript-errors-from-gstatic-but-not-in-browser

Answer (score 1):

**TL;DR**: The support for **Safari 5.1** has stopped. Solutions are upgrading the browser or use a different one.

---

The new version of Google Maps [was announced here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/google-maps-js-api-v3-notify/-GqD0WKdYnM). AFAIK the newest stable version of Google Maps is shipped since **17.12.2014** (v3.18) and does not support any version of Safari < 6.

I've found this answer from a *Google Staff* [here](https://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=7453):

> Apple has retired Safari 5.1 (and OS X 10.6 in general), last issuing
>   a (security-only) patch over a year ago.  Likewise, the Maps API is no
>   longer supporting that browser (as discussed in the FAQ as well as a
>   few other places:
>   https://developers.google.com/maps/faq#browsersupport).
>
> Browser migration is painful and sites often have no control over what
>   browsers their users visit with, but -- as browsers age -- a line must
>   be drawn somewhere. Safari 5 last got a major feature update nearly 3
>   years ago (in 5.1.4) and can no longer keep up with what's needed from
>   it.
>
> Users really should not be on OS X 10.6 either (as its last security
>   update was at the same time as Safari 5's, in September 2013), but the
>   good news for those who won't or can't update is that the latest
>   versions of both Chrome and Firefox still support 10.6, and both of
>   those are well supported by the JS Maps API.

For me the changelog was a little confusing:

> The current and previous version of Safari (Mac OS X)

This apparently does not cover discontinued versions of Mac OS X. Also Safari for Windows is not mentioned. Looking at [the support timeline](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Safari_version_history#Version_compatibility) for Safari Windows is no longer supported anyways.

- [Changelog of the Google Maps API](https://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/wiki/JavascriptMapsAPIv3Changelog)
- [Browser support of Google Maps Javascript API](https://developers.google.com/maps/faq#browsersupport)