# Capybara/Poltergeist DOM loading issues

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, phantomjs, capybara, poltergeist

I am writing a test suite using Capybara/Poltergeist combo for a website and I am coming across a situation where the DOM doesn't seem to be loading whatever I try to do.
I can see from the website snapshot that only the footer and the header are there, but not the main components of the page.

for example a page such as: https://www.udemy.com/courses/business/finance/all-courses/?lang=en&ordering=newest

```
Capybara.register_driver :poltergeist do |app|
Capybara::Poltergeist::Driver.new(app, js_errors: false,   debug: false, # change this to true to troubleshoot
 window_size: [1300, 1000] # this can affect dynamic layout
)
end
browser=Capybara.current_session
browser.visit "https://www.udemy.com/courses/business/finance/all-courses/?lang=en&ordering=newest"

sleep 15  ##giving it time to load
browser.save_screenshot('app/file1.png', full: true)
```

only the header and footer show up.

I suppose it is due to the fact that some DOM elements are loaded asynchronously, and on my current website I have the same problem.

Stuck here for 2 days now, any suggestions as to how to get the page to load properly? Thanks

Comment: Just for the sake of debugging: does sleeping for longer help?

Comment: I didnt have a problem with this code. Body loads. Check this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15733827/capybara-poltergeist-and-phantomjs-and-giving-an-empty-response-in-body?rq=1

Comment: @JaredBeck I tried up to sleep 100 to no avail.

Comment: @MesutGüneş very weird. I don't seem to be able to bring it up with this code. So if the issue is outside the code could it be some configuration problem? thx

Comment: may updating gems solve the problem.

Comment: @MesutGüneş also tried to add `  :phantomjs_options => ['--debug=yes', '--ignore-ssl-errors=yes', '--ssl-protocol=TLSv1'],` but it doesn't change anything. stuck

Comment: @MesutGüneş no luck, using rails4.2.0 ** capybara 2.5.0 ** poltergeist 1.7.0 , and running tests locally

Comment: @MesutGüneş any chance to send me the code you use to bring up that page, so I can see if there is any difference in config I have overlooked? thx

Comment: @Thrabbit sure you can get it here: https://gist.github.com/gunesmes/bcf7fd09ad7e8b658b48 and run it by `ruby udemy.rb`

Comment: @MesutGüneş Thanks for the link. I can see from your img that the body loads, but when I run exactly the same code as you, it doesn't. very weird! Still getting only the footer and the header.

Comment: running on ruby 1.9.3p545  ..maybe need to upgrade that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You most likely need to update phantomjs to 2.0+.  PhantomJS 1.9.8 which I'm guessing you're using is roughly equivalent to Safari 5 iirc and doesn't appear to work with the udemy site.

Comment: it worked! updating phantomjs from 1.9.8 to 2.0 did the trick. thanks a lot!

Comment: Note that the latest release of poltergeist (1.7.0) won't upload files when using PhantomJS 2.0, the master branch has the issue fixed